# R grouped barplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was hoping someone could point this noob in the right direction trying to create some grouped bar plots.

My data (survey responses 1=yes) looks like this

```
fac_blister8 fac_lackaccess8 fac_remote8 fac_timely8 fac_none8
          <dbl>           <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
 1            0               0           0           0         1
 2            0               0           0           0         1
 3            0               0           0           0         1
 4            0               0           0           1         0
 5            0               1           1           1         0
 6            0               0           0           0         1
 7            0               1           0           1         0
 8            0               0           0           0         1
```

I managed to create a plot for each column like this

```
q8 <-
  q8vars                        %>% 
  group_by(fac_lackaccess8)           %>% 
  summarise(name = n())      %>%
  mutate(fac_lackaccess8 = ifelse(fac_lackaccess8 == 0,"No","Yes")) 

q8_2 <-ggplot(q8, aes(x=fac_lackaccess8, y=name)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.5, color="green", fill="green") + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,22)) 

q8_2 +
  ylab("Count") + xlab("Working remotely and lack of resources")
```

Which is workable, but very cumbersome. Ideally I'd like to have all the columns in one graph with grouped bar plots for each column with yes/no.
It seems like it would be fairly straightforward, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape the data to long format, count the occurrences of yes/no in each column and plot the data with `facet_wrap` :

```
library(tidyverse)

q8vars %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  count(name, value) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(value == 0, 'no', 'yes')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=value, y=n)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.5, color="green", fill="green") + 
  facet_wrap(~name) + 
  ylab("Count") + xlab("Working remotely and lack of resources")
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you so much! I struggled with this forever. You're a star!